# Case Detail Record Custom Javascript Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a button called "Assign Back to Originator". This button is used when a rep is done working on a case and needs to assign it back to the creator of the case. The button will then assign the creator of the case as the owner. How can I throw an error of "You are already the case owner" when the creator ID and the owner ID is the same when they try to click the "Assign Back to Originator" button?

This is the code I have so far:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js")} 

if ({!Case.OwnerId=Case.CreatedById}){ 
alert('You are already the owner of the case'); 
} else { 

var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}'; 
caseObj.OwnerId = '{!Case.CreatedById}'; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]); 

if (result[0].success=='false') { 
alert(result[0].errors.message); 
} else { 
//location.reload(true); 
alert ('This case will be assigned back to the creator. You will no longer have    access to this case.'); 
window.location = '/500/o'; 
} 
}
```

Comment: Do you already having a Validation Rule enforcing this requirement and just want to surface the error? Also updated your API Version from 24.0!

Comment: You can refer my blog: https://santanuboral.wordpress.com/2017/01/23/take-ownership-of-case-from-case-details-listview/

Comment: You could get the logic to update case with owner and to throw an error referring my blog post

Comment: great blog! i'll be referring to this a lot while i learn more programming for sure. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic will look like this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}
var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
var previousOwner = "{!Case.CreatedById}";
var currentOwner = "{!$User.Id}";
caseObj.Id = "{!Case.Id}";
caseObj.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";

if(previousOwner == currentOwner)
{       
  alert("You are already the Case Owner ");     
}else
{   
  var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]); 
  alert ("This case will be assigned back to the creator.");    
  location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Santanu - as of right now, when this button is clicked, the person that clicked it has no other choice but to acknowledge that the case will be assigned back to the owner. How do I add a cancel button to the alert so the rep can go back to the page if accidentally clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You can just write:

```
if({!case.OwnerId=case.CreatedById}) {
   alert("You already own the case!");
} else {
   // do your update logic
}
```

Comment: @SantanuBoral No, it's not a typo. You only need a single equals sign in a merge formula. Try it out sometime.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: this worked like a charm. thank you very much. i'm learning a lot through you guys

Comment: @sfdcfox as of right now, when this button is clicked, the person that clicked it has no other choice but to acknowledge that the case will be assigned back to the owner. How do I add a cancel button to the alert so the rep can go back to the page if accidentally clicked?

Comment: @Paul `} else if(confirm('Are you sure you want to return the case to the original owner?')) { /* update logic here */`

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks so much for the input! if you don't mind, do you think you could show me where i need to insert that?

Comment: @Paul I just noticed your other question; I've included a full version of your code there.